# Automate data entry into the Print

Tags: list-manipulation

There are a several variables `a11`, `a12`, `a13`,...,`a21`, `a22`, `a23`,... The standard output of these variables on the screen is as follows: `Print[" a11= ", a11, " a12= ", a12, ...]`

Is it possible to somehow automate (use a loop for example) the writing of all these variables to the `Print` function?

Comment: Instead of using a11,12,... and so on, why not just use `a[1,1] a[1,2], ...` ? Also you could use a list of lists (matrix) `a = {{...}, {...}, {...}, ...}`?

Comment: @flinty, it is not very clear how to manipulate such constructs `a[1,1] a[1,2], ...` inside a function

Comment: ... what do you mean 'not very clear'? It's a lot easier than using symbols like you have, surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some variables

```
Table[Set[Evaluate[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[n] <> ToString[m]]], 
  RandomReal[]], {n, 1, 5}, {m, 1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now prints them all

```
vars = Flatten@Table["a" <> ToString[n] <> ToString[m], {n, 1, 5}, {m, 1, 5}];
Row[{#, "=", ToExpression[#]}] & /@ vars
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

You simply don't want to do this:

```
f[a[1,3]_,a[5,2]_]:=a[1,3] + a[5,2]
```

I don't mean because it's not syntactically correct, I mean that it doesn't make any sense as a function definition. When you define a function with formal arguments, you don't want to add overly specific semantics to your variables. For example, you'd never define a function that computes the area of a circle like this:

```
circleArea[radius16_] := Pi * radius16^2
```

The "16" bit just has nothing to do with the radius or circles or area or anything. It's a distraction.

So, in

```
f[a[1,3]_,a[5,2]_]:=a[1,3] + a[5,2]
```

the indices `1,3` in `a[1,3]` can't possibly *mean* anything. As they are used in the right hand side, `a[1,3] + a[5,2]`, they are just *formal arguments*.

On the other hand, if what you're trying to do is really to index into something, then the indices *do* mean something. Let's say I have

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

and I want to define a function that adds the diagonal values. I could do this:

```
f[x_] := x[[1, 1]] + x[[2, 2]]
f[a]
(* 5 *)
```

Now those indices *mean* something, but the argument `x` is still just a *formal argument* that is expected to represent a 2x2 matrix. (You could enforce and check that it is a matrix, but I haven't shown that.)

And now you can send your individual values to the `Print` function like this:

```
Scan[Print, a, {2}]
```